# Crate a launcher for Ubuntu to execute python server

Tags: command-line, server, python, launcher

I've created this launcher that executes an shell:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon[en_US]=gnome-sudoku
Name[en_US]=MServer.desktop
Exec=/home/lucasfonseca/myapplication/server.sh
Comment[en_US]=bla=foo
Name=MServer
Comment=foo
Icon=gnome-sudoku
```

On server.sh I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

python webserver/server.py
```

When I click on the launcher it open and closes. I don't get the server running.
How can I have the server running in a terminal window when I open this launcher?

Comment: Why don't you put the `python ...` command directly in the `Exec=` line? Use **full path** to _python_ executable. Please, note: Normally there are two python versions installed by default (_python_ is version 2, _python3_ is version 3.) Call the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem was the wrong path.

I used this code to get the relative path and execute the script: `.sh/server.sh`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon[en_US]=gnome-panel-launcher
Name[en_US]=Server
Exec=sh -e -c "exec \\"\\$(dirname \\"\\$0\\")/.sh/server.sh\\";$SHELL" %k
Comment[en_US]=aaaaaaaaaaa
Name=Server
Comment=aaaaaaaaaaa
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

Friendly tip: when there is an error the launcher doesn't show the terminal. So I recommend you to put something like `ping localhost` on final of your script (like mine `server.sh`), so you can view the eventual error messages when developing.